# Relay tokens between microservices with webclient

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-webclient

I have two microservices, lets name them A and B, behind a Spring Cloud Gateway. There is also an OAuthServer. When a users send a request to service A they have first to get a JWT token from the oAuthServer using the password flow.

The caveat is that service A needs to communicate with service B but for that it needs an access token. The idea is to use the JWT provided by the user when accessing service A by relaying it to service B thus making the request.

In previous versions of Spring Boot I would use `OAuth2RestTemplate` but now I need to use `Webclient`.

What I have done is to create a filter to extract the Bearer token from the incoming request in service A and then store it in a singleton class and add it manually to the outbound call.

```
@Component
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthorizationFilter.class);

private final String HEADER = "Authorization";
private final String PREFIX = "Bearer ";

private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    if (checkJWTToken(request, response)) {
        String token = extractToken(request);
        if (token != null) {
            log.info("*****RECEIVED REQUEST WITH TOKEN {}. ", token);
            log.info("***** Will store it for future requests.");
            tokenStore = TokenStore.getInstance();
            tokenStore.setToken(token);
            // setUpSpringAuthentication(token);
        } else {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}

private String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String jwtToken = request.getHeader(HEADER).replace(PREFIX, "");
    return jwtToken;
}

private boolean checkJWTToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) {
    String authenticationHeader = request.getHeader(HEADER);
    if (authenticationHeader == null || !authenticationHeader.startsWith(PREFIX))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

The `TokenStore`

```
public class TokenStore {

private static TokenStore instance;

private String token;

private TokenStore() {
}

public static synchronized TokenStore getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new TokenStore();
    }
    return instance;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public synchronized void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

}
```

And finally the web client:

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
@Profile("!default")
public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
    final WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();
    return builder;
}
```

Using it:

```
Mono<Map<Long, DrawDTO>> mono = getWebClient().get().uri(url)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenStore.getToken()).retrieve().bodyToFlux(DTO.class)
            .map(d -> Tuples.of(Long.parseLong(d.getUniqueId()), d))
            .collectMap(tuple -> tuple.getT1(), tuple -> tuple.getT2()).log()
            .onErrorMap(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> handleException(ex)).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

However, I am pretty sure that the above is a mistake. TokenStore being a singleton if two requests come from users **X** and **Y** at the same time the second filter invocation will override the token of the first. So essentially service A will use user's **Y** token to complete the request of user **X**. So in case user's **X** access level is lower than **Y** this is a security issue.

Am I wrong about the above? If yes what can I do to fix it?

One solution I found was to use client credentials for intra-service communications but I am not 100% sure how to do it with Spring Boot 2.2.6 and Spring Security 5.

Is there a correct way to do what I initially intended?

Comment: There could be several improvements here. First of all you don't have to implement your own token store. You can use one from spring-cloud-security. It also helps you with token relays etc. please check https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/reference/html/. Why do you want to check the tokens behind gateway? Are you planning to apply some authorization etc.? Using client credentials is just making a rest call to oauth service with client id and client secret. It is not a big deal and you can even get help again from spring-cloud-security to manage it in a easy way.

Comment: @cool I went own with the client credentials. However in the URL you shared I see the solution of `OAuth2RestTemplate`. I did not understand though how to do this with `WebClient`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right @idipous.I thought they are supporting both. It looks like they don't and they moved many features to spring-boot projects anyway. But there are examples out there regarding configuration of webclient. You can start with this one which at least provides a basic setup. https://medium.com/@asce4s/oauth2-with-spring-webclient-761d16f89cdd